# My iOS app every now and then refuses to launch until I reinstall it

Tags: ios, core-data, launching-application

I've got an app that uses Core Data that sporadically stops launching so I have to reinstall it using XCode and then it launches again like normal for a while, with all the Core Data information still preserved.

I have seen that an app often stops launching when the target of an app is too low in comparison to the device software version, however this is not so for this app and device (iPhone 6s).

Have you had such an issue before? What do you think could be causing this problem?

Comment: How long does it work before needing to be reinstalled?

Comment: Usually it's at least a few days, around 3 days minimum but apart from that it varies quite variable, e.g. it could be a 7-9 days sometimes

Comment: If you don't have a paid developer account then any apps you install from Xcode only last for 7 days before they have to be installed again.

Comment: @dan Mate, that sounds about right I do have a free developers account and every now and then it asks me to "Fix issue" on XCode about the signing but I just click "Fix issue" to make it work. Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that, as mentioned by dan in the comments, the code was being signed for a short period of time (7 days) and so I had to keep re-installing it on the iOS device to keep it working. Thus to keep the app working indefinitely a paid developer account is needed.

Also mentioned in this reddit forum:
https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/4hotx3/news_free_developer_account_installs_reduced_to_7/

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many, many things that could cause an app to fail to launch. You need to narrow things down and collect some data so that you can find out what the problem is and do something about it. Right now you don't even know that it's related to Core Data, you're just guessing.

For a crash on launch, look at the device console and see what messages appear when you try to launch the app and it fails. You can get the device console messages by

1. Connecting your device to your Mac
2. Opening Xcode's "Devices" window (cmd-shift-2)
3. Looking in the bottom half of the window

A better way to watch the console is to use the free [iOS Console](http://lemonjar.com/iosconsole/) app.